# Facebook Graph Api - Place photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I queried the Facebook Api with the following query to find the O2 Arena in London place:

```
search?q=02 Arena&center=51.502971,0.003026&type=place
```

I took the place named O2 Arena and browse to it:

```
https://www.facebook.com/120007384753391
```

In the page I received there is a section named photos, and by clicking it I get the photos taken in this place and the URL is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/120007384753391/photos-in
```

by querying Facebook API `/120007384753391` I get the place but querying

```
/120007384753391/photos
```

Returned an empty data..

Any idea how can I query to get these pictures ?

Comment: Are you using a page access token for that page? If not, you'll only be able to see things that are publicly available to you via the API, which is likely very little or nothing, unless some of those photos were uploaded by you

Comment: @Igy do i need us any page access token or this specific place's page access token (which obviously i dont have)

Comment: Either the page token, or a user token from someone who made one of the posts - something being visible on Facebook.com doesn't mean the same thing will be available to your via the API, because the API is more restrictive (especially when it comes to calls which fetch data of users other than the person whose token you're using)